# Как хранить информацию о классах

Tags: c++

Как сохранить в цикле имена классов и классов-родителей так, что бы при необходимости вывести какой то класс по имени так: сперва выводились имена классов родителей(а если и у этих классов есть класс родителей, то сперва их и тд), а потом уже нужный класс. Классов может быть много. У одного класса может быть несколько родителей, а у них свои родители. 
Информация об именах подается в виде списка. Не могу придумать как их хранить, что бы можно было после удобно пользоваться

```
for(auto i = iterator; i != list.end(); ++i)
{
    = i->className;
    for (int j = 0; j < i->parentCount; j++)
    {
         = i->parentName;
    }
}
```

Comment: `map<string, vector<string>>`? `multimap<string, string>`? В качестве ключей названия классов, в качестве значений их родители.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а как вывести иерархию классов

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать в каждом классе метод для вывода собственного имени, который бы рекурсивно вызывал методы базовых классов:

```
class Base
{
    public: virtual void
    EchoName(::std::ostream & output)
    {
        output << "::Base";
    }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
    public: void
    EchoName(::std::ostream & output) override
    {
        Base::EchoName(output);
        output << "::Derived";
    }
};
```

Comment: Описание классов вводится в программу в виде строки, парсится и в цикле должна записаться информация о них. Но как записать, что бы потом удобно иерархию классов выводить не знаю(

Comment: @helldrg Ну сделайте вместо `"::Base"` переменную и записывайте в нее

Comment: Т.е. предлагаете хранить в виде экземпляров класса информацию о классах. "::Base" и "::Derived" меняю на переменную и в ней храню название класса. А как наследование реализовать, что бы выводилась иерархия классов

Comment: @helldrg Наследование и вывод - без изменений

Comment: Вот так имеете ввиду https://pastebin.com/Y3XAe4VR

Comment: @helldrg Имена для каждого класса достаточно записать всего один раз. В объекты этих классов ничего записывать не надо.

Comment: как это не надо? А имена классов где хранить. Я вот в этом цикле и записываю имена 1 раз

Comment: @helldrg Имена можно сделать статическими полями, а не хранить внутри каждого объекта. А в этом цикле имена записываются для каждого класса по 10 раз, так как они записываются для каждого объекта этого класса из массива `Derived D[10];`

Comment: ну вот к примеру: первая итерация: D[0]->SetName("Vehicle"); D[0]->SetParentName(""); вторая итерация: D[1]->SetName("Car"); D[1]->SetParentName("Vehicle"); третья итерация: D[2]->SetName("Sedan"); D[2]->SetParentName("Car"); итд

Comment: @helldrg Все объекты в массиве `Derived D[10];` относятся к одному и тому же классу `Derived`, соответственно должны иметь одинаковые имена, которые достаточно ввести один раз.

Comment: тут как то чат можно создать, не могли бы пожалуйста сделать его. Просто не понимаю(